# Using Grok parser in Fluentd

Tags: logging, grok, fluentd

I am looking for a way to parse data using the grok parser, but i seem to be stuck on how to use it.
My purpose is that i would like to add additional fields using a grok patter using a filter.

Something like:

```
<filter acme.**>
    @type parser
    key_name log
    format grok
    <parse>
        <grok>
            @type grok
            grok_pattern grok_pattern %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time_stamp}%{SPACE}
        </grok>
    </parse>
</filter>
```

Using this Fluend complains or warns that a lot of stuff is not used..

- parameter '@type' in  ....is not used.
- parameter 'grok_pattern' in  .. in  section  is not used

Anu cue on how to use the Grok parser in Fluentd using a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with following configuration with Fluentd v0.12.29 included filter parser plugin.
`<parse>` section is not available with v012.29.
It has been available since v0.14 but Fluentd v0.14.8 does not include filter parser plugin.
See https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/pull/1191

And ttps://github.com/tagomoris/fluent-plugin-parser does not support Fluentd v0.14 for now.

```
<source>
  @type dummy
  tag dummy.log
  dummy [
    { "message": "Oct 24 09:01:33 mymachine uim-toolbar[5831]: Theme parsing error: <data>:2:30: The style property GtkWidget:focus-line-width is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version" },
    { "message": "Oct 24 09:01:33 mymachine uim-toolbar[5831]: Theme parsing error: <data>:3:27: The style property GtkWidget:focus-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version" },
    { "message": "Oct 24 09:01:33 mymachine uim-toolbar[5831]: Theme parsing error: <data>:2:30: The style property GtkWidget:focus-line-width is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version" }
  ]
</source>

<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  format grok
  grok_pattern %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:host} %{SYSLOGPROG}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}
</filter>

<match **>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

See also https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-grok-parser/issues/23